# how to get absolute screen position of edittext cursor?

Tags: android, android-edittext, screen

I want to retrieve the current **cursor Y position** in my EditText to show a fragment list (to set position according this Y); I want to do the same behavior like mentions list into Facebook App:

[image]

So I did that:

```
    int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
    Layout layout = editText.getLayout();
    int line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos);
    int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
    int ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line);

    int location[] = new int[2];
    editText.getLocationOnScreen(location);     

    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(pos);
    point.y = baseline + ascent + location[1];
```

It works correctly BUT when there is the scroll into my EditText, the position Y (point.y) becomes not correct... I can't understand how to have exactly the absolute Y (into screen) of the cursor in all cases (with / without scroll).

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue - you can solve this by using `editText.getScrollY()` (which returns the Y offset, in pixels, of the edittext's scroll).

So in your case:

`point.y = baseline + ascent + location[1] - editText.getScrollY();`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) with a custom [List Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

Here's an example:

In your Activity/Fragment:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_users);
CustomAdapter<User> adapter = new CustomAdapter<User>(this, R.layout.user_row, usersList);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create an object User:

```
public class User {
  public String name;
  public Bitmap image;

  public User(String name, Bitmap image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image= image;
  }
}
```

Create the row layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new class CustomAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter for the object User

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, layout, users);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the user for this position
    User user = getItem(position);

    TextView userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    userName.setText(user.name);
    image.setImageBitmap(user.image);

    return convertView;
 }
}
```